# If $S$ is closed, then any Cauchy sequence in $S$ converges to a point of $S$

Tags: real-analysis

The following is a proof that if $S$ is closed, then any Cauchy sequence in $S$ converges to a point of $S$.

> Suppose that $S$ is closed, and let $\sigma=\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ be any Cauchy sequence in $S$. Then $\sigma$ is a Cauchy sequence in $\Bbb R$, which we know is complete, so $\sigma$ converges to some $x\in\Bbb R$. Let $\epsilon>0$ be arbitrary. Then there is an $m_\epsilon\in\Bbb N$ such that $|x_n-x|<\epsilon$ whenever $n\ge m$. In particular, $x_{m_\epsilon}\in S\cap(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)$. Thus, every nbhd of $x$ contains a point of $S$, and therefore $x\in\operatorname{cl}S$. But $S$ is closed, so $\operatorname{cl}S=S$, and hence $x\in S$. This shows that every Cauchy sequence in $S$ converges to a point of $S$.

I was wondering if someone could elaborate how we go from every neighborhood of $x$ contains a point of $S$, to $x \in \operatorname{cl}S$?

> Thus, every nbhd of $x$ contains a point of $S$, and therefore $x \in \operatorname{cl}S$.

Comment: Use the triangle inequality judiciously...

Comment: @nomen: can you further explain what that means?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That depends upon the definition of closure, of course, but the usual definition of closure $\overline S$ of a set $S$ is: $x\in\overline S$ if every neighborhood of of $x$ intersects $S$. So, under this definition, the statement is true *by definition*.

If you use another concept of closure, you should tell us what it consists of.